# ob_clean doesn't clean the output before the header file?

Tags: php, header, buffer

I am facing the issue.I changed the db.php file and unfortunately I put the spaces before and after the php tags.I used this in the image.php file.I am getting the error header already sent.I know that it is because of the space in db.php but I used ob_clean in image.php.

Below is the code.

```
  spaceishere<?php
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die ('I cannot connect to the           database because: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("dbname",$con) or die  ("Cannot Connect to Database");
  ?>andhere
```

image.php file contains the code of

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
$sql="mysqlquery";
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
ob_clean();
header("content-type:image/jpg") ; 
echo stripslashes($row[imagecolumn]); 
?>
```

everything is working fine when I removed the spaces in db.php.But I cant able to understand why my ob_clean is not working.

Could you please anyone explain  it.And I dont want to change the db.php file.Because I am having problem on it.Please dont ask whats the problem.

I want to done all my changes in image.php to make it work.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should first start the output buffering by placing a call to `ob_start();` before your inclusion.

Comment: Note that it is sometimes on by default (see [`output_buffering`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering)), but a better solution is always not to have the spaces there int the first place ;)

Comment: Of course. But I assume it is always better to check the small things, like forgetting to start buffering and expecting it to be there.

Comment: This one did the trick man...You saved my time.I added the ob_start before <?php ob_start();require_once('db.php');..remainingcode ?>

Comment: No problem. Happy to have been of help :)

Comment: Also, if you take a look at php.net for ob_clean() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) then it's noted there "The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE flag. Otherwise ob_clean() will not work."

Comment: @WoodyDRN The `ob_start()` page says that all three flags are set by default.

Answer (score -2):

i think that is because you are not in "php"-mode so php does not know that something is within the output buffer, because it only knows the thing which php parses and thats within the php-tags.
So in your case the spaces are outside the php tag so php does not know of this and can not "clean" it.