# PHP String Lost After ob_clean()

Tags: php, search, redirect, header

I've had a search script running on my webpage and am expanding the search function. Currently, it searches for specific dynamic user fields. Now I would like to perform a secondary search if there are no results with the first search.

Say someone searches for "Health", the search url output would be:

"***.com/**.php?do=getall&**study**=health"

If there are no results, the follow will run:

```
    if ( preg_match( "~/(.*?)$~msi", $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ], $vv ))
    {
        $string = strstr( $vv[1], 'health=');
        $n_string = explode("=",$string);
        $url = 'http://www.****.com/***.php?do=getall&enjoys=' . $_GET[$n_string[1]];
        ob_clean();
        header('Location:' . $url);
    }
```

The url will be redirected to a alternative search field.
If I do not include ob_clean() or some variant, there will be a "Header already sent" error.

The problem is, after running ob_clean(), the value within $n_string is lost.

Thank you for any help!

---- Edit ----

Thank you all for your answers. I have found a solution to the error which was within my code. 
            $url = 'http://www.****.com/***.php?do=getall&enjoys=' . $_GET[$n_string[1]];

should have been

```
        $url = 'http://www.****.com/***.php?do=getall&enjoys=' . $n_string[1];
```

Your responses have been helpful though allowing me to clean up my method of using ob_clean().

Answer (score 0):

Try ob_end_clean() instead of ob_clean(). The ob_clean() function only clears the content of the topmost output buffer but not switching off it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the ob_clean() first - before setting the string?

Answer (score 0):

You should first start the output buffering by placing a call to **ob_start();** before your inclusion.

refer to below link 
[ob_clean doesn't clean the output before the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864863/ob-clean-doesnt-clean-the-output-before-the-header-file)